# Failed connection to the Tor Network

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help

I've just started using the latest Tor Browser, connecting through my university connection. When I try to connect, it failed to establish connection with the network after waiting for a long time. Here are the logs. My operating system is Windows 10.

[Tor Log at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gHGJtQ6f)

Comment: It looks like it's failing to connect to the bridges you're using. Have a look at obscuring your connection with pluggable transports instead.

Comment: Please post your torrc